# Differences between .NET 4 WPF Datagrid and WPF Toolkit Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

Can anyone tell me what are the differences between the WPF Datagrid included in the .NET Framework 4.0 versus the Datagrid included in the out-of-band WPF Toolkit?  I understand that the toolkit version was released first, and targets the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

I needed a WPF datagrid quick and have utilized the toolkit version in my applications.  I'm considering moving the application to .NET 4.0 and am wondering what the pros/cons will be in changing out my existing datagrids for the new ones.

Comment: I ran in to compatibility issues with .NET 4 DataGrid. See answer. Did it work out for you on Win 7, Vista and XP?

Comment: @KMC:  I ended up sticking with .NET 3.5 SP1 and the WPF DataGrid.  I haven't tried .NET 4 or the new DataGrid at all.  It's been a couple years now and I've not had any outstanding problems with it.  I also haven't used it extensively - only for readonly results.  I basically rebuilt Query Analyzer in .NET and WPF.  It's worked on XP, Vista, and 7.

Comment: thanks. may I ask which VS and OS you developed the application on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i cant remember the specifics but the 4.0 datagrid was definitely much easier to work with and you don't have to include the toolkit dll file which was pretty large. Its been a while since i switched over and i dont really see why you should use the old one as long as you have the 4.0 framework available for you and for the client computers.

Comment: Do you know of any resource that may identify differences between the two?  Also, was the new datagrid more performant?

Answer (score 2):

New input to this old post. I encountered issues when I wrote an app targeting **.NET 4 Client Profile** and heavily used WPF **DataGrid** (generated dynamically in run time). It runs OK on  .NET 4 until the program crashed and sometimes could not even start on XP and a few Window 7 (especially of languages other than English). I checked Fusion log and eventvwr and .NET compatibility seems to be the cause.

I reluctantly back ported my app from **.NET 4** to **.NET 3.5**. But **.NET 3.5** does not ship with **DataGrid**, so I have to implement **WPF Toolkit**. The **DataGrid** in **WPF Toolkit** is slightly slower I found, but it is more portable.

Comment: I found the Toolkit DataGrid to be extremely buggy in a lot of situations, especially for screen readers/GUI automation tools.  Disabling virtualization helped a bit tho.

Comment: @KMC: I ended up sticking with .NET 3.5 SP1 and the WPF DataGrid. I haven't tried .NET 4 or the new DataGrid at all. It's been a couple years now and I've not had any outstanding problems with it. I also haven't used it extensively - only for readonly results. I basically rebuilt Query Analyzer in .NET and WPF. It's worked on XP, Vista, and 7.